# Downloading a docx file in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, docx

I am trying to make a download action that downloads a Word doc generated in the 'download' controller using PHPDOCX. So far PHPDOCX is able to save the desired .docx file in the correct folder, but something goes wrong when I try to download it. Since Media Views were deprecated, I must use the CakeResponse file method as suggested in the CakePHP 2.x Cookbook:

```
// In the controller:
$this->response->file($file['path'], array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));
return $this->response;
```

I was able to use this method for to export an RTF with no problem (the RTF was generated using PHPRTFLite), but when I use the method for a .docx file using PHPDOCX I receive the following error in Firefox:

> The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found
>   when prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. When viewed in a
>   differently-configured browser, this page will reload automatically.
>   The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024
>   bytes of the file.

I would like to use a document generator that accepts HTML, which is why I chose PHPDOCX.  Considering the above error, I set off to define the headers and content-type using the following method:

`$this->response->header(array('Content-type'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'));`

But I still receive the same error in CakePHP:

> The requested file APP/files/info_sheets/filename.docx was not found or not readable

One thing I was thinking is that PHPDOCX sends many errors when it generates the document and this is interfering with the Mime-type or encoding.  But according to the 2.x Cookbook:

> Headers are not sent when `CakeResponse::header()` is called either.
>   They are just buffered until the response is actually sent.

Another idea is that I need to set the character encoding in the header right after the content-type:

`$this->response->header(array('Content-type'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;charset=utf-8'));`

But this results in garbled text.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?  The "download.ctp" view file is currently blank.  Please let me know if you need additional information about this issue.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might try to disable autoRender, otherwise CakePHP might still try to render your view and layout;

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Also, haven't tested it, but have you tried this to set the header:

```
// register the type 
$this->response->type(array('docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'));
// set the type for the response
$this->response->type('docx');
```

See the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, it helped solve this problem!  I registered the type as suggested and lowered the debug level to 0 using `Configure::write('debug', 0);` in the controller.  Lowering the debug level prevented PHPDOCX from writing the PHP error 'notices' it produces to the page.  The autoRender did not seem to make a difference, so I did not include it in my original posting.  Either way, this now works as desired.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: if you use autoRender false you do not have to "return" the response object in your action. it will automatically stop rendering any view and process the response afterwards. I personally find that a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @mark just wondering, will the 'return' be required to perform unit-testing? I just read about unit-testing and redirect(); for them to work properly, there should be a return

Comment: depends on how you test, I guess. since the response object is a public attribute and therefore part of the controller you can still access it and work with it any time after the action has been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the media.php file in the core of the framework and add the mime-type to the array that have the types.
Eg:

```
'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```